# Add mysql OR php trigger to change datetime format from US to UK for any query that return datetime

Tags: php, mysql, date, datetime, yii

I have A system build on YII  using US date format, by my client ask me to change the format to UK format, the problem is the system is too big and I can not take around the whole system code to change the presenting format.

is there a way to add a trigger for date,datetime fields to return in UK format in php or mysql.

thanks

Comment: Dates are stored in an internal format in the database.  You should just be able to change the internationalization settings for the database, and it should work, assuming you are using native types everywhere and not doing explicit `format()` statements.  In any case, a trigger won't help, because they do not affect `select` statements.

Answer (score 0):

You asked:

> is there a way to add a trigger for date,datetime 
>   fields to return in UK format in php or mysql.

No.

The MySQL internal datetime format is not changeable. The only locale-sensitive setting in the DBMS is the language in which the names of months and weekdays are rendered. In the US, we got those names from England. So that doesn't help.

If you want MySQL to render dates from its tables in Euro format (25.12.2015) you need this.

```
     DATE_FORMAT(datevalue, '%e.%c.%Y')
```

If you have the dates in php, you can use this sort of thing.

```
    date('j.n.Y', $datevalue);
```

Many php applications offer a global $DATEFORMAT string constant, that can be changed for use in a different locale.  You may want to adapt your code to do this. For example, the WordPress team have sorted this out very nicely indeed. https://codex.wordpress.org/Formatting_Date_and_Time